# PyQT5. Рow to pass value from UI to program

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have programm class

```
class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    def advanceGears(self):
        self.gear1Rot += 10 #speed
        self.update()
```

and UI class

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(599, 560, 271, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider.setStyleSheet("background: none")
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider.setRange(0, 50)
        self.horizontalSlider.setValue(0)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickPosition(self.horizontalSlider.TicksAbove)
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.update)
```

How i can pass value from UI horizontall to programm function. I need to change the value 10 in the advanceGeats function to those values ​​that are in the QSlider. I tried using speedChanged = pyqtSignal(int) in a function but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm using it wrong. I would appreciate any hint or help on how to do this, I need to change the values ​​according to the QSlider value.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your attempts, but be also aware that editing pyuic generated files is considered bad practice, so try to follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.